# How to add a X509Certificate2 to Identity Server 4 on a shared hosting service

Tags: c#, security, ssl, .net-core, identityserver4

I've been trying to create a basic Identity Server 4 app (.Net Core 3.1) and host it on a shared hosting service and spend an awfully long amount of time trying to figure out the deployment process, getting lost more and more reading one article after another in the process!!!  -_-

1. Is this possible?
2. Is it at all possible to read a PFX from the Content root folder or am I missing something here?

   ```
   services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(
           new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "keyBag.pfx"), "password"))
   ```
3. If not what are your suggestion as to what I should do here?!